# Alpine shell can't find folder

Tags: python, linux, docker, 7zip, alpine-linux

This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-alpine3.7

RUN mkdir folder_1
RUN mkdir folder_2
RUN apk --update add build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python-dev py- 
pip p7zip libc6-compat libstdc++
RUN pip install fabric3 boto3 csvsort

EXPOSE <port>

ADD directory/ /
CMD ["python", "scriptname.py"]
```

The application runs a series of steps, one of which is to extract 7z files from folder_1 to folder_2. It is able to find the folder_1 and the source folder, but unable to find folder_2. I logged into the container to make sure the folder exists, and it does.

I found another question with a similar problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/883625/alpine-shell-cant-find-file-in-docker and also installed libc6-compat and libstdc++ according to the answer.

This is the line of code that's failing:

```
os.system('7za x ' + source_path + file_name + ' -' +
              file_decryption_password +
              ' -o' + destination_path)
```

Here, destination_path is 'folder_2/' and the exact error that I get is

```
sh: -ofolder_2/: not found
```

The command and the docker work fine on my mac laptop and the docker fails on the Linux based server.

Comment: Switches should come before arguments. See documentation for 7za. Try `os.system('7za x - -o' + destination_path + ' -p'  + file_decryption_password + ' ' + source_path + file_name)`

Comment: The command will be interpreted by the shell, so any `; & $ # ! * ` special characters will have special meaning. A good idea would be to enclose passwords and paths and names in `"`.

Comment: what's the full path to 7za  inside the container (run `which 7za`)? Could be an issue with it not being in your $PATH in the container

Comment: I copied your dockerfile, and your script and it works for me...

Comment: The docker runs on my laptop as well, but not on the server, on AWS